# Python share values

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

In my project I have multiple flags like this:

```
file_a = False
file_b = False
file_c = False
```

I'm trying to run two processes: one (call it A from now) handles incoming messages on message queue, second (call it B from now) handles some data processing. B operates on boolean flags, and A sets its values:

```
def a():
    while True:
        ...
        ...
        file_a = True
        ...

def b():
    while True:
        ...
        if file_a:
            process(file_a)
            ...

a_proc = Process(target=a)
b_proc = Process(target=b)
a_proc.start()
b.proc.start()
```

But, the values don't seem to change. I read that I should use threading, and it seems to work, but my guideline is to use multiprocessing instead of threads.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you need to exchange data between processes with multiprocessing module, you can directly share memory:

## `multiprocessing.Value`

Value is a wrapper around a ctypes object, which has an underlying value attribute representing the actual object in memory. All Value does is ensure that only a single process or thread may read or write this value attribute simultaneously.

```
from multiprocessing import Value
file_a = Value('i', 0)
file_b = Value('i', 0)
file_c = Value('i', 1)
```

This will create shared integer values for your file flags. Since it's python, the conversion between integer values and boolean values is simple:

```
>>> Value('i', True)
<Synchronized wrapper for c_int(1)>
>>> Value('i', False)
<Synchronized wrapper for c_int(0)>
>>> bool(Value('i', False).value)
False
>>> bool(Value('i', 50).value)
True
```

Preference of a taste, but maybe a better option, you can use `c_bool` from `ctypes`:

```
from multiprocessing import Value
from ctypes import c_bool
file_a = Value(c_bool, False)
file_n = Value(c_bool, False)
file_c = Value(c_bool, True)

>>> Value(c_bool, False)
<Synchronized wrapper for c_bool(False)>
>>> Value(c_bool, 5)
<Synchronized wrapper for c_bool(True)>
```

## `multiprocessing.Manager` dictionary:

To collect multiple boolean flags, you could use dictionary, but it needs to be shared between processes, so Manager() comes in handy.

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
manager = Manager()
flags = manager.dict({'file_a' : False, 'file_b' : False, 'file_c' : True})

>>> flags
<DictProxy object, typeid 'dict' at 0x7f70822f06d0>
>>> flags['file_a']
False
>>> dict(flags)
{'file_a': False, 'file_c': True, 'file_b': False}
```

## And finally collecting it all together:

I will go with Manager approach, simply because it will make the code cleaner:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
manager = Manager()

    def a():
        while True:
            ...
            ...
            flags['file_a'] = True
            ...

    def b():
        while True:
            ...
            if flags['file_a']:
                process(file_a)
                ...

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        flags = manager.dict({'file_a' : False, 'file_b' : False, 'file_c' : True})
        a_proc = Process(target=a)
        b_proc = Process(target=b)
        a_proc.start()
        b.proc.start()
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

Your `file_a, file_b, file_c` are being loaded into each process separately. You need to use `Value` from `multiprocessing`

Comment: Your answer could really use some explanations and examples

Comment: @akalikin im new here. will add comment

Comment: @akalikin sorry i cant comment yet

Comment: Question... can't you pass the (manager) managed variable (dict) to each process?  Process(target=a,args(flags,)) and Process(target=b,args(flags,)), thus def a(flags) and def b(flags).  The flags variable not passed by reference if this is done?  Now that the managed variable is 'shared' seems the object reference should work?