# pool.apply_async and global variable

Tags: python, asynchronous, global-variables, apply, threadpool

Because i cant run simply program with pool.apply_async and global variable, I need a help. I cant resolve a problem with shared memory.
Short description a program flow:

How should this program works:
Variable config.variable is a flag - default False. If something goes wrong in thread value of this flag should be set to Thru and value True should stop/Pause.
In other words
Idea is that fail inside a async proces should stop/pause program.

I tired do something with multiprocessing Value and Manager but with no result. I do not know it is  my fail or it will never work. I am too weak for solving this problem. Not enough skills. Selv-learning is hard.
I readed similar thread for example this [Python share values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822013/python-share-values) or [Python multiprocessing Pool.apply_async with shared variables (Value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430355/python-multiprocessing-pool-apply-async-with-shared-variables-value) but there is about passing argument into a thread. Most of others examples use Value or Manager but with Process and this solution work for me.

Question are:
Can I use Value or Manager for pool.apply_async? How to do it for changing a global variable.
What kinde of typecodes should I use for boolean True and False

I read this : [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

Please help me and show how should i write it.
I attache simply code.
Can somebody edit it and add missing lines?
I can not change apply_async to process.

File config.py

```
variable1 = False
```

File main.py

```
import config
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import sys

def func2():
    try:
        config.variable1 = True
        print('Global Variable in thread {}'.format(config.variable1))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while 1:
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            pool = Pool(4)
            pool.apply_async(func2)
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        # print(config.variable1)
        print('Global Variable in main loop {}'.format(config.variable1))


        if config.variable1 is True:
            sys.exit(0)
```

How to use Value or Manager in this case?
Can somebody add few line?

Tank you for help and explanation.

Comment: _Most of others examples use Value or Manager but with Process and this solution work for me._ I'm confused, what does or doesn't work? Also, I don't see the point of `except Exception as e:`, and I believe it is discouraged. I would suggest using a context manager for that pool, and writing `while True:` instead of `while 1:`. In fact, what is the purpose of that loop in the first place?

Comment: Do not work changing a global variable with pool.apply_asynch.While 1 is only for test reason.  I wrote this because I waited for changing a value config.variable1.I tried use with Menager as menager: but I stuck. Value of my variable was not changed

Comment: Martineau - from your answer was helpful only  " I would suggest using a context manager for that pool" rest not on the topic. thx for help

Comment: Okay, that makes a bit more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for someone who will need it.
I edited example from [16.6.1.4. Sharing state between processes¶](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
import config
from threading import Thread
import time

def f(d):

    if d['flag1'] is False:
        d['flag1'] = True
    else:
        d['flag1'] = False
    # l.reverse()

def stop():
    print('stop')
    while 1:
        if config.variable1 is True:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    print(config.variable1)

    d = manager.dict()

    thread1 = Thread(target = stop)
    thread1.start()

    while 1:
        d['flag1'] = config.variable1
        pool = Pool(4)
        p = pool.apply_async(f, args=(d,))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        config.variable1 =  d['flag1']

        print (d)
        print(config.variable1)
        if thread1.is_alive() is False:
            break
        time.sleep(3)
```